# why the code doesn't work when I use 'vue-property-decorator'? (Vue.js+TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

I'm using Vue.js + TypeScript, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work with 'vue-property-decorator'. These two pieces of codes aim to do the same thing. Can you help me pointing out where I do wrong?

This code **works**:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "DetailPage",
  props: ["id"],
  data() {
    return {
      profile: [{}] as Array<object>
    };
  },
  methods: {
    findProfile(id?: string) {
      this.profile = [];
      axios
        .get("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/" + this.id, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.VUE_APP_MYVUE}`
          }
        })
        .then(res => {
          this.profile = res.data;
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.profile = [];
        });
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route(to: string, from: string) {
      this.findProfile();
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.findProfile();
  }
});
</script>
```

But this one with 'vue-property-decorator' **doesn't work**:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
import axios from "axios";

export default class DetailPage extends Vue {
  @Prop() readonly id!: string;
  private profile: Array<object> = [];
  findProfile(id?: string) {
    const profile: Array<object> = []
    axios
      .get("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/"+ this.id , {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.VUE_APP_MYVUE}`
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
      
  }
  
  @Watch("$route", { immediate: true, deep: true })
  onUrlChange(to: any, from: any) {
    this.findProfile();
  }
  beforeMount() {
    this.findProfile();
  }
}
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try replacing `@Prop() readonly id!: string;` with `@Prop(String) id: string;` to see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

The @Component decorator indicates the class is a Vue component

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
import axios from "axios";

 @Component({
        name: 'ComponentName',
        components: {example, exampleTwo}
    })

export default class DetailPage extends Vue {
  @Prop() readonly id!: string;
  private profile: Array<object> = [];
  findProfile(id?: string) {
    const profile: Array<object> = []
    axios
      .get("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/"+ this.id , {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.VUE_APP_MYVUE}`
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
      
  }
  
  @Watch("$route", { immediate: true, deep: true })
  onUrlChange(to: any, from: any) {
    this.findProfile();
  }
  beforeMount() {
    this.findProfile();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oops yes! I forgot to type as

@Component
export default class DetailPage extends Vue {....

But that doesn't solve the issue, unfortunately.. :(